# using apply to pass in an object for the this keyword

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to teach myself Javascript, but I seem to be stuck at a rather basic step.
My reference book says:

> "apply can be used to pass in an object for the `this` keyword to
>   point to".

I first start with:

```
var a = 50;
var foo = function() {
    return this.a;
}
```

When I do `foo()`, I get `50` as expected. Then I attempt the `apply` as follows:

```
foo.apply({a : "blah"});
```

When I do `foo()` once again, I still get `50` and not `blah` as I was expecting.

It seems like `apply` wasn't successful in making the `this` keyword point to the `{a : "blah"}` object.

I'm almost certain I am misunderstanding something. Can you help clarify?

Comment: The "apply" method only calls the method with specified "this" and array of arguments. It doesn't create a new function as the "bind" does. See details about apply function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: Do `console.log(foo.apply({a : "blah"}))` and you'll get `'blah'`. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `apply()` method doesn't modify the function in any way; it simply calls the function with the specified `this`.

You can use `bind()` to make a new function that always calls the original with a specified `this`:

```
var myFoo = foo.bind({ a: 'blah' });
myFoo();
```